# Checkboxes don't stick to hidden/unhidden rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with a bunch of checkboxes. On this page there is also a button to hide/unhide entire rows. Sometimes when I unhide the rows, the checkboxes will move on top of eachother to the first of the unhidden rows. Is there any way to fix this?

The hide/ Show code is literally just

```
   Sheet1.Rows("73:75").Hidden = False
```

and

```
    Sheet1.Rows("73:75").Hidden = True
```

Some other code related to the checkboxes:

On startup of the workbook:

```
    For Each cObj In .OLEObjects
        'checkbox OK off/red
        posInstr = InStr(cObj.Name, "chkOK")
            If posInstr > 0 Then
                cObj.Visible = False
                cObj.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
     Next
```

Comment: I believe that here is what you are looking for. Good luck!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137495/hide-checkboxes-when-hiding-rows You just need to change some properties of your checkboxes.

Comment: I guess this is it. I tried a few times and see if it stays. Will mark as answered then. Thanks

Comment: @JentevanHeuverswyn This sort of works, but be careful if you're doing other things to your sheet like inserting rows this can go wrong.

Comment: @David I will keep it in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the checkbox is not 'in' a cell, but on a fixed location on the sheet. I remember trying to solve this problem some time ago with limited success. You can set the location and visibility of the checkbox in code to the location and visibility of the row it is linked to. However it was very hard to reliably get that information as excel has so many different mechanisms to hide rows. I could not manage to make it work nicely.

Instead I made a different solution which looked a little less nice but worked perfectly. I just captured the cell selection event, added a check if it was in the range of selectable cells and either added an X or removed it, so that it looked like a selection. You could even use the checkbox symbols from the webdings2 font. You could check the column for positive checks to see which rows are checked.

Comment: The thing is that my other objects like combobox etc don't have this problem which is weird to me